# application.css file not being loaded from browser cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

[image]

Website is running on Puma production server.
Every time I go to another page, the application.css file is also downloaded every time. But the application.js is loaded from cache successfully.

Answer (score -1):

From rails official document.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => "reload" %>
```

Comment: I think this is for js. From docs:

Then you can use the data-turbolinks-track attribute to force a full page reload when you deploy a new JavaScript bundle.